# Style Chapter Title format

Tags: chapters

I have a lot of trouble recreating a chapter title just like this one:[image: Desired output]

I have tried using the fncychap packages. But I can't get to make the horizontal line appear or the title actually center.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the package [`titlesec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec).

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\Large}{Chapitre\quad\thechapter}{0mm}{\newline\hrule\vspace*{.5\baselineskip}\centering\uppercase}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\chapter{Pricing european options in a discrete time model for the limit order book}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to achieve it using this method